# Responsive row of divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a row of divs that will span the width of the screen. The div must have a fixed height and width and the divs will drop to another line the screen width has already been filled. I am also trying to apply media queries so that the divs, when in a smaller screen will span the entire width.

Media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .test {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 100% height:150px;
        padding:10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:599px) {
    .test {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 30% height:150px;
        padding:10px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
    .test {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 20% height:150px;
        padding:10px;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/

As you can see the div changes height when there is multiple lines of text in it. How can I ensure each div is kept the same height eve if one has more text?

Comment: you need to include a semi-colon after your width!

Comment: @Aaron - this should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you are looking for this:

```
.test{
    background-color: skyblue;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 150px; 
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I updated  your fiddle for visual experience.
[**jsfiddle**:fixed width and height and divs will drop to another line the screen width has already been filled](https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/3/)

Comment: This partially works, however the long text gets hidden when the screen size is reduced. I'm guessing this is because of the overflow:hidden. I need all the text to still be visible.

Comment: you are right. you would have to remove overflow:hidden. if you want fixed height then you would have to be cautious about text length though.

Comment: you should accept the answer once your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

you have written

```
width: 100% height:150px;
```

but it should be

```
width: 100%; height:150px;
```

same applies to other occurences

i updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/1/

you can use *vertical-align:top*  for better visual appearance:
https://jsfiddle.net/9deLmbps/2/

Comment: The text appears outside of the box when it is reduced to a mobile size in your example.